# SQL Server connection string keywords act as case sensitive although they shouldn't be

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string, keyword, case-sensitive

I use .NET's OdbcConnectionStringBuilder to update a connection string read from a config file, which makes its keys lower case, as documented by MS ("Data Source" -> "data source").

The connection string is used to access MS SQL Server (2008, if it makes a difference).

It works fine on my machine (Windows 7 32 bit), and according to [MS's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254978.aspx) it should work:

> Keywords are not case sensitive

However, on several other machines (at least some are 64 bit), the connection to DB could not be opened with this lower case. Only after changing the keywords manually to their original casing (upper case on the letter of each word) the DB connection was opened.

The keywords in the connection string (all were modified to lower case):

- `Data Source`
- `Initial Catalog`
- `Integrated Security`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at collation settings?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This isn't related to case sensitivity of the database instance, but the connection string properties.